# Nested scan block inside select block

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, I want to select some lines from a file that match a regex and then store to a list.

So I write the following code:

```
    def get_valid_instr istream
         p istream.select { |line| line.scan(/(^\s*\w+\s*;\s*\w+\s*$)/){|instr| instr[0].upcase.strip.split(";")}}
    end

   trace_instr = File.open("#{file_name}", "r"){|stream|  get_valid_instr stream}
```

The output is simply the display of all file.
If I put a print in scan block, I see exactly what I want.
There are other ways to do that (filling an external list) but I wonder why it doesn't work and if there is ruby way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a block to `scan`, it will return something different than if you don't:

```
"abc".scan(/./)
# => ["a", "b", "c"]

"abc".scan(/./) {|l| puts l }
# a
# b
# c
# => "abc"
```

You need to be aware of this when using `scan`.

However, even better than your current solution would be to use [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). You can pass *both* your regular expression and your block to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see some of the data you want to test with.

Is the data split by line? I'm not sure about you splitting by the semi-colon. What's the reason for that? If you could post some example data and some example output, I'll be able to help further.

This is my attempt at interpreting what you're trying to achieve, but it may be well off as I've not seen real data. Thanks!

```
def get_valid_instr(lines)
  regex = /(^\s*\w+\s*;\s*\w+\s*$)/
  lines.inject([]) do |matched_lines, line| 
    if match = line.match(regex)
      p match[0]
      matched_lines << match[0].upcase.strip.split(";") 
    end
    matched_lines
  end
end
trace_instr = get_valid_instr(File.readlines(file_name))
pp trace_instr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_valid_instr istream
  istream.grep(/^\s*\w+\s*;\s*\w+\s*$/).map do |instr|
    instr.upcase.strip.split(";")
  end
end
```